# How do I monitor failed logon attempts in Windows?

Tags: windows, security, authentication, winlogon, gina

Is there any reliable way to monitor failed logon attempts on-the-fly in Windows XP? (well, Vista too for that matter).
I need to monitor failed logon attempts programmatically which is currently accomplished with a simple [GINA Stub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375198(VS.85).aspx) by subclassing the Login dialog from MSGINA.

However, my current solution is not waterproof if there are other GINAs in the chain.

**So my question is**: Is there any (other) API I can rely on? Or do I have to roll out an entire GINA replacement DLL?

Comment: You should ask on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Sweet, thank you for the link

Comment: Here is my question at sereverfault.com: http://serverfault.com/questions/13989/how-do-i-monitor-failed-logon-attempts-in-windows

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the Windows Event Log - the Security or System Log should have these events.

You can monitor the event log either manually with the Event Viewer administrative tool, or programmatically.